# C++ constructor with argument-list

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments, pass-by-reference, move-constructor

I'm getting familiar with constructors in C++, and wondering why my C++ compiler can't find the constructor with an argument-list.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

const int defaultAge = 0;
const std::string unknown = "unknown";

class Patient {

    public:
     int age;
     std::string dob;
     std::string name;

    public:
     Patient();                                                           // Default Constructor
     Patient(int &years, std::string &birthdate, std::string &aliase);    // Argument-List Constructor
     void print();
};

Patient::Patient() : age(defaultAge), dob(unknown), name(unknown) {
    puts("Patient information from default consturctor:");
}

Patient::Patient(int &years, std::string &birthdate, std::string &aliase) 
: age(years), dob(birthdate), name(aliase) {
    puts("Patient information from copy consturctor:");
}

void Patient::print() {
    printf(" Name - %d\n DOB  - %s\n Name - %s\n", age, dob.c_str(), name.c_str());
}

int main(void) {

    Patient p0;
    p0.print();

    Patient p1(40, "August 11, 1980", "John Doe");
    p1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when attempting to compile the code:

[compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaAsO.png)

I'm using Apple clang version 11.0.0 as my compiler

Comment: Why are you passing `int` by reference?  Just pass it by value.

Comment: The errors should be posted as text, not images, but the problem would be because `"John Doe"` is of type `const char [9]`, which will be converted to a temporary `std::string` value to pass it to the constructor.  However, the constructor takes a non-const string reference, which cannot bind to a temporary object.  Change the constructor to take its two string parameters as `const string &`, or just take them as `string` (no reference).

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the parameters as lvalue reference to non-const, which can't be bound to rvalues like `40` (which is an `int` literal), `"August 11, 1980"` and `"John Doe"` (which are string literals and would be converted to `std::string` implicitly as temporories, which are rvalues).

You can make them lvalue reference to const (for both the declaration and definition), e.g.

```
Patient(const int &years, const std::string &birthdate, const std::string &aliase);
//      ^^^^^             ^^^^^                         ^^^^^
```

Or for `int` just make it pass-by-value.

```
Patient(int years, const std::string &birthdate, const std::string &aliase);
//      ^^^        ^^^^^                         ^^^^^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PDbvGf15ITen4p7X)

Answer (score 1):

songyuanyao points out the problem with your code. A good alternative is to pass by value and then move:

```
Patient::Patient(int &years, std::string birthdate, std::string aliase) 
    : age(years), dob(std::move(birthdate)), name(std::move(aliase))
{
    puts("Patient information from copy consturctor:");
}
```

In your original code (or songyuanyao's fix) then every string content is allocated twice , whereas in this version there is one allocation and one move .

As a rule of thumb, pass by value any time that the function is going to store a copy of the argument.